# How to cluster data that have different scale?

Tags: time-series, clustering

I'm looking for a way to cluster data points that do not share the same scale
here is an example:

```
[ID]    [category]   [category_mean]    [category_Q1]   [category_Q3]    [category_median]
1          a               2                  0.9            1.7                 1.5
2          B              20                  9              17                  15
3          c              200                 90             170                 150
4          d             2000                 900            1700                1500
5          E             20000               9000            17000               15000
```

What you notice here, the scale is so different like for example when you plot the scatterplot of the median and q3 you get something like this:
[image: image1]
[image: image2]
you can clearly see that the scale of the points on the very left (image1) is way bigger then the scale of the points the very right (image1)
And when we zoom in (image2) we can that the scale keeps on shrinking
what I'm trying to do, is find a way to cluster or group these points as showing in the image2
**Note**: I don't think I can scale these points on the same scale (not sure yet) but I would consider any suggestion
Also, please note that I'm working on timeseries data, the provided dataframe example is a creation of my mine to explain more

Comment: Instead of your original values x use their logarithm log(x).

Comment: I would consider that, thank you!